# I am unable to load the data from this code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

So, i am attempting to create an application in swift 3.0 which reuses the same view but each time loading diffrent information

```
    else if TestSpace == 20 {

let tb1 = a1.text;
UserDefaults.standard.set(tb1, forKey: "tc1")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let tb2 = a2.text;
UserDefaults.standard.set(tb2, forKey: "tc2")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let tb3 = a3.text;
UserDefaults.standard.set(tb3, forKey: "tc3")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let tb4 = a4.text;
UserDefaults.standard.set(tb4, forKey: "tc4")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let tb6 = a6.text;
UserDefaults.standard.set(tb6, forKey: "tc6")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let tb5 = a5;
UserDefaults.standard.set(tb5, forKey: "tc5")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

}

}




@IBAction func load(_ sender: UIButton) {

if TestSpace == 1 {
func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


    let ad1 = UserDefaults.standard
    a1.text = ad1.string(forKey:"ac1")


    let ad2 = UserDefaults.standard
    a2.text = ad2.string(forKey: "ac2")


    let ad3 = UserDefaults.standard
    a3.text = ad3.string(forKey: "ac3")


    let ad4 = UserDefaults.standard
    a4.text = ad4.string(forKey: "ac4")

    let ad6 = UserDefaults.standard
    a6.text = ad6.string(forKey: "ac6")


    let ad5 = UserDefaults.standard
    a5 = ad5.object(forKey: "ac5") as! UIImageView!

    }
```

this is what i have got this far also i have encountered 2 issues 1. I continuously receive errors with my else if statement the second one where i am attempting to recall the data 2. it doesn't load any data which may be linked to my first issue. I am completely stuck and any help would be much appreciated and i think there is a possibility that i am doing this completely the wrong way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `let ad1 = UserDefaults.standard` and `let ad2 = UserDefaults.standard`, it's the same object, why ?

Comment: How are you expecting to get an `UIImageView` from `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: And format the code to have a cleaner view of what you are trying to do

Comment: I was unsure on how to save and recall the         UIImageView so i thought i would give the same method i use to save text a try unforuntaly i couldnt get that far...

Comment: i know that the way i have coded it thusfar is not the most staight forward or conventional way of doing it and i know there are ways i could make it more streamline however this has been working for other apps i have completed and if its not broken why fix it?  larme i didnt even relise they were the same object they are titled diffrently

Comment: @Yellow Even if it works on other app, this is not a reason to write bad code. You have to respect the best practices if you want your code to be maintanable and readable... So first, you dont need to create 6 times the same var...

Comment: I had a missing parenthesis so thats why i was receiving errors with the if else statement a really basic fault however i still down know or haven't worked out how to reuse the view